# Make search box to give same output for input as "abc123" or "abc 123"

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is an drop down search box which is working perfectly.....
But i want that, as it contains a option of Contact us, so if anyone searches for contact us like "contactus" or "contact us". In both the case it shows the same result...
Means, searching abc123 or searching for abc 123 gives same result.
I dont want to add 2 options for this.
Pls help!

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */

function hideOptions() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
}

function showOptions() {
  hideOptions();
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if( input.value === ''){
      hideOptions();
      return false;
  }
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else if(a[i].classList.contains('fixed-input') === true) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  showOptions();
}
.div {
  display: none;
}
```

```
.dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 7px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="text" class="dropbtn" placeholder="Search Here..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support" class="fixed-input">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    <a href="#tools">Cyber Warriors YouTube Channel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use for example `regular expressions` to search for spaces in the text and use the `replace` to remove spaces. e.g. : `myTxt.replace(/\s+/g, '')`

Comment: sorry, i have tried  something like this. But after this the search box stops working and dint showed any result. Might i have done something wrong. Can you please show a snippet??

Comment: I added an answer. Note: But in this situation, even for example by typing 'contact anything ...' it will display contact. If you do not want to comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use the [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method.

I changed the following line: `if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)`

by: `if (txtValue.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter) || filter.startsWith(txtValue.toUpperCase()))`

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */

function hideOptions() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
}

function showOptions() {
  hideOptions();
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if( input.value === ''){
      hideOptions();
      return false;
  }
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase()
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter) || filter.startsWith(txtValue.toUpperCase())) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else if(a[i].classList.contains('fixed-input') === true) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  showOptions();
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div {
  display: none;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 7px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="text" class="dropbtn" placeholder="Search Here..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support" class="fixed-input">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    <a href="#tools">Cyber Warriors YouTube Channel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: But in this situation, even for example by typing 'contact anything ...' it will display contact. If you do not want to comment

Answer (score 0):

Can use REGEX to achieve this

```
input = document.getElementById('myInput')
text=input.value // text = 'example one'
text = text.replace(/\s+/g,'') // text = 'exampleone'
```